# define a not std year period for pandas cumsum

Tags: pandas, cumsum

I have a long time series with datetime index. I want to cumsum yearly but I want define my years as 1 oct to 30 sept next year

```
ex: cum sum on 1 oct 2018 to 30 sept 2019
```

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to manually mask `10,11,12` as next year:

```
# toy data
s = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2017-09-01', '2017-10-01', '2017-11-01'])
df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2], index=s)

# mask Oct, Nov, Dec
groups = np.where(df.index.month > 9, df.index.year + 1, df.index.year)
# array([2017, 2018, 2018], dtype=int64)

df.groupby(groups).cumsum()
```

Second option is to convert the index to fiscal year:

```
groups = df.index.to_period('Q-SEP').qyear
# Int64Index([2017, 2018, 2018], dtype='int64')
```

Output:

```
            0
2017-09-01  0
2017-10-01  1
2017-11-01  3
```

Comment: I like fiscal way, clean one line... Thank for these 2 options!